# How to put event Listener to 20 forms on a page having different names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 20 forms in my web page

```
<form id="post_comment_1" class="post_comment" action="cmt.php" method="post">

// form inputs

</form>
```

.......

```
<form id="post_comment_20" class="post_comment" action="cmt.php" method="post">

// form inputs

</form>
```

Now, I have to track the form submit using javascript. if there is only one form having id (post_comment) I can track it like this

```
$("#post_comment").submit(function(event){

    // function statements    

});
```

But I can not do this because I have about 20 forms on one page. What is the efficient way to have an event listener on each of the form submit??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.post_comment').submit(function(evt) {})
```

Answer (score 1):

try [attribute selector with `^`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) this will select all the ids beginning with the given string..

```
 $("form[id^='post_comment'").submit(function(event){
      .....
```

or class

```
$('.post_comment').submit(function(event) {
  .....
```

class selector is better and faster than the attribute selector.. so i would go with class selector.. (if you can add a class to your form )

from doc

> attributeStartsWith selector : However it will be slower than using a class selector so leverage classes, if you can, to group like elements.

Comment: Which of them is more efficient??